# directory name not permitted in url

Tags: html, model-view-controller, iis-7

This is a weird issue that I've resolved but I'm just wondering if anyone knows the cause of it.  I have a number of directories under a directory named images.  They inherit the same permissions and new ones always work fine.  Yesterday I created a directory named 'archive001' but 'mysite/images/archive001/myimage.jpg' threw a 403 error.  After sleeping on it I changed the directory name to 'archv001' and woohoo it worked fine.  I remember have the same problem in the past but with a couple words I can't remember - using IIS7 and asp.net mvc.  Not a critical issue but just curious if anyone has any idea why this happened? I only tested it in chrome

Comment: Can you check what sub status it is? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: duh -- was a rewrite rule that I must have added long ago that appears to be something to block spiders - not sure when or why but disabling it get rid of the issue... its always something .. Thanks @LexLi

Comment: You might post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a rewrite rule that I must have added some time ago (programs been running since 2010 or so).  Rewrite was to prevent spiders and had to be something I copied somewhere.  Disabling it got rid of the issue. Thank you @LexLi.

Any comments on the use of the spider rewrite rule?